# TinyMCE pasted text from MSWord underlines all

Tags: javascript, ms-word, copy-paste, tinymce-4

I have implemented TinyMCE v4.1.9 with my MVC application, and it works except for few issues.

1. When I Copy and Paste normal text from MSWord, TinyMCE underlines all the pasted text.
2. I want to preserve explicitly underlined text from MSWord.
3. Paragraphs copied from Notepad, select all and add bullets will add only a single bullet point to all the text.

Here is my configuration, any help is appreciated.

```
    plugins: 'paste',
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u/span,br,ol,ul,li,p",
    force_br_newlines: true,
    force_p_newlines: true,
    forced_root_block: false,
    paste_word_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u/span,br,ol,ul,li,p",
    paste_preprocess: function (pl, o)
    {
        //keep bold,italic,underline,lists,paragraphs
        o.content = strip_tags(o.content, '<b><i><u><ul><li><p><br>');
    }
```

`strip_tags` function is the same as in [paste_preprocess tinymce issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520608/paste-preprocess-tinymce-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experimented the TinyMCE configuration settings in various combinations and the working configuration change I have to do is given below. Other settings are the same.

instead of:

```
valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u/span,br,ol,ul,li,p",
paste_word_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u/span,br,ol,ul,li,p",
```

corrected:

```
valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u,br,ol,ul,li,p",
paste_word_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em,u,br,ol,ul,li,p",
```

Removed accepting `<span>` tags for underlines.